# Fixed size of image in list

Tags: list, office-365, url, image

I have a list with a column of type url/image, formatted as image. When I put a link to a large image, it shows the image in full size.
Is it possible to restrain the size, to a fixed size, say 200x200px?

Edit: Maybe I should add that I use Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options you can attempt;

Open the AllItems.aspx in SharePoint Designer (SPD) and convert the list to XSLT dataview, then specify the width and height for the image column.

Secondly, you could create a new custom field type.

Thirdly, you could potentially write some CSS via SharePoint Designer, to force all images to appear in your defined height and width.

The preferred route, would be going with the first option.

Comment: Is it also possible in Office 365?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure in Office 365 MT (multi-tenant). I know this works in Office 365 Dedicated, for certain.